# Python perceptron zip error

Tags: python, typeerror

I am trying to implement a perceptron on my dataset, and when running it, I keep getting an error saying:

> TypeError: zip argument #2 must support iteration

Here's the code I put in:

```
ppn = Perceptron(eta=0.1, n_iter=10)
ppn.fit(X,y)
plt.plot(range(1, len(ppn.errors_)+1), ppn.errors_, marker='o')
plt.xlabel('Epochs')
plt.ylabel('number of misclassifications')
plt.show()
```

Here is the perceptron I implemented:

```
class Perceptron(object):
    def __init__(self, eta=0.01, n_iter=10):
        self.eta = eta
        self.n_iter = n_iter
    def fit(self, X, y):
        self.w_ = np.zeros(1 + X.shape[1])
        self.errors_ = []
        for _ in range(self.n_iter):
            errors = 0
            for xi, target in zip(X, y):
                update = self.eta * (target - self.predict(xi))
                self.w_[1:] += update * xi
                self.w_[0] += update
                errors += int(update != 0.0)
            self.errors_.append(errors)
        return self

    def net_input(self, X):
        return np.dot(X, self.w_[1:]) + self.w_[0]

    def predict(self, X):
        return np.where(self.net_input(X) >= 0.0, 1, -1)
```

Comment: The error means what it says... `y` is not a `list`... If you disagree, you better show the code that creates `y` too.

Comment: As already said, `y` needs to be a `list` of samples in your implementation - or anything iterable. `X` and `y` must have the same length, or number of rows - otherwise you'll get errors.

Answer (score 0):

y needs to be iterable. Use a list or tuple, or make sure that the class of the object has an __ **iter** __ method defined.